# Java type cast issues in input buffer

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I have a code for reading an Input stream..But when i am casting the character to Integer, I am getting an error

"  method Integer.parseInt(String,int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Integer.parseInt(String) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to String) ".. Here is the code

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.*;

class Abc{

    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int age = Integer.parseInt(br.read());
        String s = br.readLine();
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println(age); }
}
```

Comment: What is the format of your input?

Comment: Sir input is an Integer followed by a string..Also sir my doubt is although inputstreamreader reads input character by character, readLine reads whole string and looks similar to scanner.nextLine which breaks it in tokens using delimiter format.. How then the string and character stream have same characterstic? Like when i do  Integer.parseInt((sc.nextLine())  & Integer.parseInt((br.readLine()) , both produce the same result although br breaks input into character while scanner breaks it in tokens using delimiters.?

Answer (score 0):

Because `br.read()` already returns an int, you cannot cast it to an int.

Also, when you run your program, you are going to get wierd outputs and you wont be able to enter a value for `String s`. The following code uses `int age = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());` instead of `int age = br.readLine()`, and the issue is fixed.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Abc
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    { 
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int age = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        String s = br.readLine();
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println(age);
    }
}
```